# Keyboard cursor loses focus when I'm typing

Tags: keyboard, dell, cursor

When I'm typing a text in OpenOffice on Ubuntu 11.10/12.04 using the keyboard of Dell Inspirion 1525, the cursor loses focus and I start to typing in another place on screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is very likely because your hand brushes the touch pad while you're typing.

If you pull up the settings dialog (I think you can click the cog thing up in the top right and then click settings or control center or something along those lines ... alternatively, hit the super/windows key and start typing "settings" and it should show up) you can go to the "Mouse and Touchpad" section. There will be an option you'll want to check in the touchpad tab: "Disable touchpad while typing"

Comment: I have this problem with touchpad disabled while typing. I forgot to comment it.

Comment: does it work? I mean ... test it. Try typing with one hand and touching the touchpad with the other.

Answer (score 1):

I found a Dell problem faq that solved the problem!  There are hot keys for the different laptop models that turn the mousepad on and off.  For mine it was Fn + F3.  Now the mousepad is disabled until wanted.  Solved the jumpy focus problem of having two active mice at one time.